# A value of type 'Future<FirebaseUser> Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

This line is causing me trouble

```
User fUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is supposed to return `User` but dart gives me an error saying that it is returning `Future<FirebaseUser> Function()` instead. I got this line of code straight from the documentation (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage). I have already run `flutter pub upgrade` so I am using the latest version of FirebaseAuth.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is incorrect, I suspect it's from somewhere else.

Anyway, current user is nullable so:

```
User? fUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: That's the error that Android Studio shows. Anyway, I tried upgrading all dependencies with `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` and now FirebaseAuth works but loads of other dependencies don't.